# Can't read raspberry Tx

Tags: python, uart

I'm trying to do a project with raspberry and a PIC. The PIC sends data via UART using Tx of PIC and Rx of the Raspberry.  But when I try to read data in the raspberry there's no anything. I put a LED in the Tx and I can see how this blink.

The configuration that I using is:

Raspberry pi 1
PIC16f887
I edited the '/boot/cmdline.txt'
I used the minicom to verify the communication

I'm using this script of python

```
#import lib
import time
import serial
import asyncio

from ubidots import ApiClient

#verify
print("Inicio del programa")

#Token
api = ApiClient(token ='A1E-ly09T6yKjc5jUyZebHxcdq7p6C8S3j')

print("Token ok")

#upload variable's key

hum = api.get_variable('5b07a0c1c03f975b1cd397e3')
gndh = api.get_variable('5b07a0dac03f975ae5051ffa')
Temp = api.get_variable('5b07a0adc03f975ae5051fec')
solar = api.get_variable('5b07a0ecc03f975a9a85e54c')

print("Variables OK")

#update with port for Arduino
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0', 9600)

print("pic OK")

async def ciclo():
    while True:
        ser.flushInput() #Reset buffer

        read_serial = ser.readline()
        humReading = float(read_serial) #convert to float
        new_value = hum.save_value({'value': humReading})
        print(read_serial)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.250)

        read_serial = ser.readline()
        gndhReading = float(read_serial) #convert to float
        new_value = gndh.save_value({'value': gndhReading})
        print(read_serial)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.250)

        read_serial = ser.readline()
        TempReading = float(read_serial) #convert to float
        new_value = Temp.save_value({'value': TempReading})
        print(read_serial)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.250)

        read_serial = ser.readline()
        solarReading = float(read_serial) #convert to float
        new_value = solar.save_value({'value': solarReading})
        print(read_serial)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.250)

        time.sleep(3)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(ciclo())
loop.close()
```

Comment: for starters `ser.flushInput()` would discard any data stored in the os buffers during the `time.sleep(3)`, you might want to avoid that because its the same data you are trying to read on the next line. second you could check (from a terminal) if `cat /dev/ttyAMA0` prints the information the PIC is transmitting. if it does print correctly (or just about anything which is possible if the port settings are incorrect), its probably something in this script else its either the wiring or the PIC side

Comment: Which Pi model?  Which operating system and version?  Where is a photo of your wiring?

Comment: Hopefully the pic is running 3.3V as well, and not using 5V logic?